# How to update value directly in firebase realtime database inside dynamic key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set "pretend" value using the following code but it didn't work.

```
dataBase.ref().orderByChild('en_word').equalTo('pretend').set({
  en_word: 'Pretend'
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a value to the Firebase requires that you know the complete, exact path where you want to write. It doesn't support so-called update queries, where you send a query and a write operation to the database in one go. Instead you will have to:

1. Execute the query.
2. Loop over the results.
3. Update each of them in turn.

So in your case that'd be something like:

```
let query = dataBase.ref().orderByChild('en_word').equalTo('pretend');
query.once("value").then((results) => {
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.update({
      en_word: 'Pretend'
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it fixed my issue :) 
Also, could you please guide me about the reference for this info "snapshot.ref.update" so I can learn more about it?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref?